# Adding html tags to text disables button functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

See the code below. I have full page sections, each with a button. When the button is pressed I want the page to proceed to the next section. Everything worked fine except when I  enclosed the text in the section in `<h1></h1>` or `<p></p>` tags. For example, see Sections 1 and 2, where for some reason the button is not working after I added these tags. It is working in other sections. Even in Section 1, if I remove the `<h1></h1>` tag it works fine. What do these tags have anything to do with the functionality of the button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Selecting multiple DIV tags with jquery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

        html{
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
            backround-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 48px;
            color: rgb(90,90,90);
        }

        .slide {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            padding:20px;
            height: 95%;
            width: 100%;
            font-family: Georgia;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <section class="slide">
        <h1>This is the first div.</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="slide">
        <p>This is the second div.</p> 
    </section>


    <section class="slide">This is the third div.</section>

    <section class="slide">This is the fourth div.</section>

    <section class="slide">This is the fifth div.</section>

    <section class="slide">This is the sixth div.</section>



    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Assign ids to each section in the order they appear.

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("section").each(function(index){
            idtag = 's' + (index + 1)
            $(this).attr('id', idtag);
            $(this).append('<button>Next div</button>');
            $(this).css('opacity', 0);
        });


    var presentation = function() {

        $("section").each(function(index){
            $(this).css('opacity', 0);
        });     
        // Check if the current url points to a specific id. If not point
        // it to id = 1, otherwise point it to the id specified in the URL.

        var currenturl = $(location).attr('href');


        var indexhash = currenturl.lastIndexOf('#')

        if (indexhash === -1) {
            var newurl = currenturl + '#s1';
            $("#1").css('opacity',1);
            window.location.href = newurl;
        }
        else {
            var currentid = currenturl.substring(indexhash, currenturl.length);
            console.log(currentid);
            $(currentid).css('opacity', 1);
            window.location.href = currenturl;
            // window.location.assign(currenturl);
        }

    };

        var nextdiv = function() {
            currenturl = location.href;
            currentid = location.hash;
            console.log(currentid);
            newidnum = parseInt(currentid.substring(currentid.indexOf('s')+1, currentid.length),10)+1;
            newid = "#s" + newidnum;
            newurl = currenturl.substring(0,currenturl.lastIndexOf('#'))+newid;
            console.log(newurl);
            window.location.href = newurl;

        };

        // $(document).ready(presentation);
        presentation();
        $(window).bind('hashchange', presentation);
        $('button').bind('click', nextdiv);

    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you using Sections, and not divs?

Comment: Looks like your whole script should be inside a `$(document).ready(...)`, not just `presentation`.

Comment: Yea, i dont see anything in the jquery form of $(function(){...});

Comment: @Fallenreaper [HTML5](http://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-section-element)

Comment: Thanks @Mathletics  They More you know... :)

Comment: @Mathletics: I put the whole script inside $(document).ready(...) and all sections had opacity=1 and the button was not visible. Again, that seems so unexpected.

Comment: Can you update the post so you have the current state of your code?

Comment: The problem of opacity=1 was my mistake...I had not enclosed the script in function(){} within `$(document).ready()`. Nevertheless, my original problem remains even after putting everything inside `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the HTML elements within your section elements, it has to do with the fact that you've stacked all your element on top of each other and set the opacity to zero instead of actually hiding them with the display property (`display:none` vs `opacity:0`). You can see this if you remove all but the first section element that it works fine. Also, if you inspect your code with a tool like Chrome's developer tools, you'll see that the sixth section element is actually the topmost one, and blocking everything below it. You're also clicking the same top button every time and not the button that's a child of the section element. You can see that by assigning an id to each button and then console logging it with `$('button').click(function(){console.log($('button').attr('id'));});`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was thinking of asking if there is a better alternative to opacity and it crossed my mind that I may have this problem of overlapping of elements with something else. Although I did not thing that the problem posted here was related to that. It is strange that the problem appeared only after adding the html tag elements and not before that. Thanks for your answer. It is working fine now.